# Algorithm to detect and combine overlapping / colliding circles

Tags: java, algorithm, 2d, collision-detection

I'm trying to write a time efficient algorithm that can detect a group of overlapping circles and make a single circle in the "middle" of the group that will represent that group. The practical application of this is representing GPS locations over a map, put the conversion in to Cartesian co-ordinates is already handled so that's not relevant, the desired effect is that at different zoom levels clusters of close together points just appear as a single circle (that will have the number of points printed in the centre in the final version)

In this example the circles just have a radius of 15 so the distance calculation (Pythagoras) is not being square rooted and compared to 225 for the collision detection. I was trying anything to shave off time, but the problem is this really needs to happen very quickly becasue it's a user facing bit of code that needs to be snappy and good looking.

I've given this a go and I it works with small data sets pretty well. 2 big problems, it takes too long and it can run out of memory if all the points are on top of one another.

The route I've taken is to calculate distance between each point in a first pass, and then take the shortest distance first and start to combine from there, anything that's been combined becomes ineligible for combination on that pass, and the whole list is passed back around to the distance calculations again until nothing changes.

To be honest I think it needs a radical shift in approach and I think it's a little beyond me. I've re factored my code in to one class for ease of posting and generated random points to give an example.

```
package mergepoints;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Merger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Merger m = new Merger();

        m.subProcess(m.createRandomList());

    }

    private List<Plottable> createRandomList() {
        List<Plottable> points = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            Plottable p = new Plottable();
            p.location = new Point((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
                    (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
            points.add(p);
        }
        return points;

    }

    private List<Plottable> subProcess(List<Plottable> visible) {

        List<PlottableTuple> tuples = new ArrayList<PlottableTuple>();

        // create a tuple to store distance and matching objects together,
        for (Plottable p : visible) {
            PlottableTuple tuple = new PlottableTuple();
            tuple.a = p;
            tuples.add(tuple);
        }

        // work out each Plottable relative distance from
        // one another and order them by shortest first.
        // We may need to do this multiple times for one set so going in own
        // method.

        // this is the bit that takes ages

        setDistances(tuples);

        // Sort so that smallest distances are at the top.
        // parse the set and combine any pair less than the smallest distance in
        // to a combined pin.
        // any plottable thats been combine is no longer eligable for combining
        // so ignore on this parse.

        List<PlottableTuple> sorted = new ArrayList<>(tuples);
        Collections.sort(sorted);

        Set<Plottable> done = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Plottable> mergedSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (PlottableTuple pt : sorted) {
            if (!done.contains(pt.a) && pt.distance <= 225) {
                Plottable merged = combine(pt, done);
                done.add(pt.a);
                for (PlottableTuple tup : pt.others) {
                    done.add(tup.a);
                }

                mergedSet.add(merged);
            }
        }

        // if we haven't processed anything we are done just return visible
        // list.
        if (done.size() == 0) {
            return visible;
        } else {
            // change the list to represent the new combined plottables and
            // repeat the process.
            visible.removeAll(done);
            visible.addAll(mergedSet);
            return subProcess(visible);
        }
    }

    private Plottable combine(PlottableTuple pt, Set<Plottable> done) {
        List<Plottable> plottables = new ArrayList<>();
        plottables.addAll(pt.a.containingPlottables);
        for (PlottableTuple otherTuple : pt.others) {
            if (!done.contains(otherTuple.a)) {
                plottables.addAll(otherTuple.a.containingPlottables);
            }
        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (Plottable p : plottables) {
            Point position = p.location;
            x += position.x;
            y += position.y;
        }
        x = x / plottables.size();
        y = y / plottables.size();

        Plottable merged = new Plottable();
        merged.containingPlottables.addAll(plottables);
        merged.location = new Point(x, y);

        return merged;
    }

    private void setDistances(List<PlottableTuple> tuples) {

        System.out.println("pins: " + tuples.size());
        int loops = 0;
        // Start from the first item and loop through, then repeat but starting
        // with the next item.
        for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < tuples.size() - 1; startIndex++) {
            // Get the data for the start Plottable
            PlottableTuple startTuple = tuples.get(startIndex);
            Point startLocation = startTuple.a.location;

            for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < tuples.size(); i++) {
                loops++;

                PlottableTuple compareTuple = tuples.get(i);

                double distance = distance(startLocation, compareTuple.a.location);

                setDistance(startTuple, compareTuple, distance);
                setDistance(compareTuple, startTuple, distance);

            }
        }
        System.out.println("loops " + loops);
    }

    private void setDistance(PlottableTuple from, PlottableTuple to,
            double distance) {
        if (distance < from.distance || from.others == null) {
            from.distance = distance;
            from.others = new HashSet<>();
            from.others.add(to);
        } else if (distance == from.distance) {
            from.others.add(to);
        }
    }

    private double distance(Point a, Point b) {
        if (a.equals(b)) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        double result = (((double) a.x - (double) b.x) * ((double) a.x - (double) b.x))
                + (((double) a.y - (double) b.y) * ((double) a.y - (double) b.y));
        return result;
    }

    class PlottableTuple implements Comparable<PlottableTuple> {
        public Plottable a;
        public Set<PlottableTuple> others;

        public double distance;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(PlottableTuple other) {
            return (new Double(distance)).compareTo(other.distance);
        }
    }

    class Plottable {
        public Point location;
        private Set<Plottable> containingPlottables;

        public Plottable(Set<Plottable> plots) {
            this.containingPlottables = plots;
        }

        public Plottable() {
            this.containingPlottables = new HashSet<>();
            this.containingPlottables.add(this);
        }

        public Set<Plottable> getContainingPlottables() {
            return containingPlottables;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The title is a short description. The specifics of what the code is supposed to do should be in the question. Please clarify what you *want* to achieve. E.g., What does "combining" mean here?

Comment: Sorry I meant to go back and change that before posting and then forgot.

Comment: Can you give a more precise specification for how you want to "combine" things? Your current code seems to give different output depending on the order in which you iterate through points. Do you want a faster way to achieve the exact same results, or are you just looking for any fast algorithm that produces a clustering that seems "reasonable"?

Comment: The second one, it just needs to look OK but it needs to be quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map all your circles on a 2D grid first.  You then only need to compare the circles in a cell with the other circles in that cell and in it's 9 neighbors (you can reduce that to five by using a brick pattern instead of a regular grid).

If you only need to be really approximate, then you can just group all the circles that fall into a cell together.  You will probably also want to merge cells that only have a small number of circles together with there neighbors, but this will be fast.

Comment: Thanks for this, There will be cases where every point is actually in the same grid so the distance thing will still take inordinate amounts of time. However combining all items in the grid is something we have come up with independently and i'm trying this now. If this is still taking it's time we will try doing it only for what is on screen but that will still be everything at some points.

Comment: You don't need to do any distance checking in that case at all though.  Any points in the same grid cell must be within a certain distance, so you can just group all of them together.  This approach fails because you can have 2 points really close to each other that end up in different cells.  This should be fine though if both cells are heavily populated, so you only really need to deal with the cells that have a small number of points in them.

Comment: Indeed I was refering to your first solution of doing distance checking within the grid and surrounding. The combining one is what I am attempting to implement, unfortunately fell at the first hurdle of making a 8000x8000 2d array.

Comment: This works very quickly and looks great for the most part, I am getting overlaps in certain situations and i'm thinking about a solution to this by applying the same algorithm again on the results with an offset grid. Though I'm not sure quite how yet.

Comment: I was thinking an offset grid would probably work well too.  It's basically the same as having a grid where the size of the cells is halved in each dimension.  Each of these smaller cells potentially belongs to one of four bigger 2x2 squares of 4 cells.  Choosing which is not necessarily trivial, but you will probably be able to get fairly good results without too much complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is going to take a reasonable amount of computation no matter how you do it, the question then is: can you do all the computation up-front so that at run-time it's just doing a look-up? I would build a tree-like structure where each layer is all the points that need to be drawn for a given zoom level. It takes more computation up-front, but at run-time you are simply drawing a list of point, fast.

My idea is to decide what the resolution of each zoom level is (ie at zoom level 1 points closer than 15 get merged; at zoom level 2 points closer than 30 get merged), then go through your points making groups of points that are within the 15 of each other and pick a point to represent group that group at the higher zoom. Now you have a 2 layer tree. Then you pass over the second layer grouping all points that are within 30 of each other, and so on all the way up to your highest zoom level. Now save this tree structure to file, and at run-time you can very quickly change zoom levels by simply drawing all points at the appropriate tree level. If you need to add or remove points, that can be done dynamically by figuring out where to attach them to the tree.

There are two downsides to this method that come to mind: 1) it will take a long time to compute the tree, but you only have to do this once, and 2) you'll have to think really carefully about how you build the tree, based on how you want the groupings to be done at higher levels. For example, in the image below the top level may not be the right grouping that you want. Maybe instead building the tree based off the previous layer, you always want to go back to the original points. That said, some loss of precision always happens when you're trying to trade-off for faster run-time.

[image]

**EDIT**

So you have a problem which requires O(n^2) comparisons, you say it has to be done in real-time, can not be pre-computed, and has to be fast. Good luck with that.

Let's analyze the problem a bit; if you do no pre-computation then in order to decide which points can be merged you have to compare every pair of points, that's O(n^2) comparisons. I suggested building a tree before-hand, O(n^2 log n) once, but then runtime is just a lookup, O(1). You could also do something in between where you do some work before and some at run-time, but that's how these problems always go, you have to do a certain amount of computation, you can play games by doing some of it earlier, but at the end of the day you still have to do the computation.

For example, if you're willing to do *some* pre-computation, you could try keeping two copies of the list of points, one sorted by x-value and one sorted by y-value, then instead of comparing every pair of points, you can do 4 binary searches to find all the points within, say, a 30 unit box of the current point. More complicated so would be slower for a small number of points (say <100), but would reduce the overall complexity to O(n log n), making it faster for large amounts of data.

**EDIT 2**

If you're worried about multiple points at the same location, then why don't you do a first pass removing the redundant points, then you'll have a smaller "search list"

```
list searchList = new list()

for pt1 in points :
    boolean clean = true
    for pt2 in searchList :
        if distance(pt1, pt2) < epsilon :
            clean = false
            break
    if clean :
        searchList.add(pt1)

// Now you have a smaller list to act on with only 1 point per cluster
// ... I guess this is actually the same as my first suggestion if you make one of these search lists per zoom level. huh.
```

**EDIT 3: Graph Traversal**

A totally new approach would be to build a graph out of the points and do some sort of longest-edge-first graph traversal on them. So pick a point, draw it, and traverse its longest edge, draw that point, etc. Repeat this until you come to a point which doesn't have any untraversed edges longer than your zoom resolution. The number of edges per point gives you an easy way to tradeoff speed for correctness. If the number of edges per point was small and constant, say 4, then with a bit of cleverness you could build the graph in O(n) time and also traverse it to draw points in O(n) time. Fast enough to do it on the fly with no pre-computation.

[image]

Comment: The points can be anything. They come from a set of user defined parameters from a database. It needs to be quick.

Comment: I don't understand how that change anything ... are you saying that the list of points will change completely and very often? How many points are we talking about anyway, 10? 100? 100000000?

Comment: Yes, they will change frequently and completely very often.

Comment: If every point is on top of the other then they will all still be in the same bounding box and it will take just as much time.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying, I have basically gotten to the exact same conclusion as you but i need a solution so i'm looking for a fresh perspective. There's no way to do pre-computation, there's no way to know what the points will be until the user is literally trying to look at them. I've seen this sort of thing work on google maps so i'm hoping there's a way to solve this. Thanks for your help but "good luck with that" comments aren't really appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't like my answer. I'm willing to keep thinking about this with you and look for faster heuristic approaches, but not if you're just going to shoot down every idea that's suggested to you, I am actually trying to help you.

Comment: There's no shooting down. I simply cannot pre process anything. I get a set of database results of objects that contain gps co-ordinates and a user expects them to instantly display on screen. I know it's unreasonable but it's what I've been tasked with. I need something that can take 50,000 or 100,000 or 1,000,000 points and show them on screen combined with their totals almost instantly.

Comment: Ok. That's a very hard problem, but interesting. I'll keep brainstorming ideas and putting them up as they come to mind, maybe one will inspire to something that you can actually use.

Comment: @Link19 "There's no shooting down. I simply cannot pre process anything" - Or are just not willing to accept that you may need to do preprocessing at some other point, e.g. when loading the database? Mike shows you some good ideas for a starting point, yet you seem to not *seriously* consider them. Good luck then, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess and something that occurred to me while reading responses from others.

Do a multi-step comparison.  Assume your combining distance at the current zoom level is 20 meters.  First, subtract (X1 - X2).  If This is bigger than 20 meters then you are done, the points are too far.  Next, subtract (Y1 - Y2) and do the same thing to reject combining the points.

You could stop here and be happy if you are good with using only horizontal/vertical distances as your metric for combining.  Much less math (no squaring or square roots).  Pythagoras wouldn't be happy but your users might.

If you really insist on exact answers, do the two subtraction/comparison steps above.  If the points are within horizontal and vertical limits, THEN you do the full Pythagoras check with square roots.

Assuming all your points are not highly clustered very close to the combining limit, this should save some CPU cycles.

This is still approximately an O(n^2) technique, but the math should be simpler.  If you have the memory, you could store distances between each set of points and then you never have to compute it again.  This could take up more memory than you have and also grows at a rate of approximately O(n^2), so be careful.

Also, you could make a linked list or sorted array of all your points, sorted in order of increasing X or increasing Y.  (I don't think you need both, just one).  Then walk through the list in sorted order.  For each point, check the neighbors out until (X1 - X2) is bigger than your combining distance. and then stop.  You don't have to compare each set of points for O(N^2), you only have to compare neighbors that are close in one dimension to quickly prune your large list to a small one.  As you move through the list, you only have to compare points that have a bigger X than your current candidate, because you already compared and combined with all previous X values.  This gets you closer to the O(n) complexity you want.  Of course, you would need to check the Y dimension and fully qualify the points to be combined before you actually do it.  Don't just use the X distance to make your combining decision.